# Focus on element only after state-change

Tags: reactjs

I have a collapsible div that holds form inputs and a submit button on the bottom of the page.

OnSubmit if there is an error, it should open the closed div and focus on the first element in error. I was able to change that into a working algorithm but the problem is it tries to focus and it doesnt work because the div hasn't been uncollapsed yet.

I show some code

```
if (!errorExists) {
      this.registerCompany();
    } else {
      this.props.handleCompanyError(() => {
        const firstErrorElement = document.getElementsByName(arr[0])[0];
        firstErrorElement.focus();

        firstErrorElement.scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth',
          block: 'center',
          inline: 'center',
        });
      });
    }
  };
```

So basically this.props.handleErrors() changes a state that makes sure the div gets opened if its closed. But the focus does not work. So how can I refactor the above code to make sure that the focus and scroll into view only occurs after this.props.handleErrors() finishes its state change job